# Cholesky decomposition and rotation matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I implemented three methods for inversion of a matrix, all are classic.
I wanted to test for the most generalized method, while taking efficiency into account.

For Cholesky decomposition, which is relatively efficient, the matrix $A$ should be positive or semi positive definite. It is known for a matrix $A$ to be positive definite, its eigenvalues must be positive. Now, in the case of rotation matrices, their eigenvalues represent modes "think of frequency, if that is a proper interpretation", and therefore are complex "or real". In such case...is there a such thing as a reliable Cholesky decomposition for the inversion of an arbitrary rotation matrix.

Note: $R^{-1}=R^T$ for rotation matrices "orthogonal", but still, i would like to test for explicit inversion using Cholesky method with forward and backward substitution

Comment: Cholesky works on **symmetric** positive definite matrices.  An arbitrary rotation matrix is not necessarily symmetric.  (For example, a Givens rotation.)  Also, what is your measurement for efficiency?  Operation count?

Comment: The measure for efficiency is rather an optimization effort, meaning anything less than what Cholesky $ < O(n^3)$  .So based on your answer , just go head and use LU as a generic method for an inversion of a matrix. Is there any more efficient methods..say in the order of $O(n^2)$

Comment: Operation count is measured in the approximate number of flops-- e.g., $O(n), O(n^2)$, etc.  As for a general inversion method of $O(n^2)$-- well, that's the million dollar question in numerical linear algebra.